# Spotfire Web Player force new session

Tags: spotfire

How does one force a new session in the web player?

I am tiling multiple analyses (6) in a web page with iframes, and sometimes (50/50) all but one error out seeming to grab the same session as the one that succesfully loads.  In theory if i can add a url parameter that says 'new session' i can force 6 distinct sessions.

> Error:"The requested analysis is not loaded on the server. The
>   analysis with id 'a4afc9575f43c2046c4c1- 281400259cfe04' is not found
>   in session 'jxqmqvizv5zxoyvhulnj3nmh' in application instance
>   '281400259cfe04'. This may indicate that the server has been
>   restarted. (For additional information see server log file or supplied
>   detailed message). "

Comment: there are a few known causes for this message, but I'm not sure if any of them relate to your scenario: https://www.tibcommunity.com/docs/DOC-4098 . another thing to check is that the KeepAlive service is enabled and configured correctly (you should be able to tell if the KeepAlive log is filling up). finally, look at your Windows Event Log at the time when this happens to see if there's anything that shouldn't belong.

Comment: thanks for your response, i do not get this error when i open any of the URL's that the iframe is calling directly, only when they are opened simultanesouly on the page with multiple iframes

Comment: odd. are you seeing any message in the Spotfire logs when this happens? can you share that info (sanitized, of course)?

Comment: I have switched to using the Javascript API direcly so that it is handling each frame as its own session